# Overriding the handling behavior for standard Spring MVC exceptions

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, exception

Spring Boot seems to have a default behavior for handling certain exceptions.
I have a rest controller. If I do not handle `HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException` in the `@ControllerAdvice` annotated rest controller, the application returns a default JSON response containing the error message.

I do not want to replace this JSON response, but I do want to log additional information (e.g. log certain requestor's IP address) when it happens.

Is there a way to do this with an `@ExceptionHandler` annotated method, or other mechanism?

Comment: Do you mean you want a custom JSON response, or just additional logging when this happens?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Spring MVC configures indeed an exception handler for you.
By default, [`DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.html) is used as stated in the class javadoc :

> Default implementation of the `HandlerExceptionResolver` interface that
>   resolves standard Spring exceptions and translates them to
>   corresponding HTTP status codes.
>
> This exception resolver is enabled by default in the common Spring
>   `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet`.
>   That is right for MVC controllers.

But for exception handlers for REST controllers (your requirement here), Spring rely on the `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` class.
The first class have methods that return `ModelAndView`s while the second class have methods that return `ReponseEntity`s.

You can define a custom exception handler by annotating your class with `@ControllerAdvice` in both cases (MVC and REST controllers) but since your requirement is for REST controllers, let's focus on that.

Besides annotating a custom exception handler with `@ControllerAdvice`, you can also make that to extend a base exception handler class such as [`ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.html) to override some behaviors.
`ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` implementations allows to know all the exceptions actually handled and mapped.  Look at the `handleException()` method that is the facade method of the `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` class :

```
/**
 * Provides handling for standard Spring MVC exceptions.
 * @param ex the target exception
 * @param request the current request
 */
@ExceptionHandler({
        HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.class,
        HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException.class,
        HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException.class,
        MissingPathVariableException.class,
        MissingServletRequestParameterException.class,
        ServletRequestBindingException.class,
        ConversionNotSupportedException.class,
        TypeMismatchException.class,
        HttpMessageNotReadableException.class,
        HttpMessageNotWritableException.class,
        MethodArgumentNotValidException.class,
        MissingServletRequestPartException.class,
        BindException.class,
        NoHandlerFoundException.class,
        AsyncRequestTimeoutException.class
    })
@Nullable
public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleException(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    if (ex instanceof HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException) {
        HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED;
        return handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported((HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException) ex, headers, status, request);
    }
    else if (ex instanceof HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException) {
        HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE;
        return handleHttpMediaTypeNotSupported((HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException) ex, headers, status, request);
    }
    else if (ex instanceof HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException) {
        HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE;
        return handleHttpMediaTypeNotAcceptable((HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException) ex, headers, status, request);
    }
    else if (ex instanceof MissingPathVariableException) {
        HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
        return handleMissingPathVariable((MissingPathVariableException) ex, headers, status, request);
    }
    else if (ex instanceof MissingServletRequestParameterException) {
        HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
        return handleMissingServletRequestParameter((MissingServletRequestParameterException) ex, headers, status, request);
    }
    else if (ex instanceof ServletRequestBindingException) {
        HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
        return handleServletRequestBindingException((ServletRequestBindingException) ex, headers, status, request);
    }
    else if (ex instanceof ConversionNotSupportedException) {
        HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
        return handleConversionNotSupported((ConversionNotSupportedException) ex, headers, status, request);
    }
    else if (ex instanceof TypeMismatchException) {
        HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
        return handleTypeMismatch((TypeMismatchException) ex, headers, status, request);
    }
    else if (ex instanceof HttpMessageNotReadableException) {
        HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
        return handleHttpMessageNotReadable((HttpMessageNotReadableException) ex, headers, status, request);
    }
    else if (ex instanceof HttpMessageNotWritableException) {
        HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
        return handleHttpMessageNotWritable((HttpMessageNotWritableException) ex, headers, status, request);
    }
    else if (ex instanceof MethodArgumentNotValidException) {
        HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
        return handleMethodArgumentNotValid((MethodArgumentNotValidException) ex, headers, status, request);
    }
    else if (ex instanceof MissingServletRequestPartException) {
        HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
        return handleMissingServletRequestPart((MissingServletRequestPartException) ex, headers, status, request);
    }
    else if (ex instanceof BindException) {
        HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
        return handleBindException((BindException) ex, headers, status, request);
    }
    else if (ex instanceof NoHandlerFoundException) {
        HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND;
        return handleNoHandlerFoundException((NoHandlerFoundException) ex, headers, status, request);
    }
    else if (ex instanceof AsyncRequestTimeoutException) {
        HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE;
        return handleAsyncRequestTimeoutException(
                (AsyncRequestTimeoutException) ex, headers, status, request);
    }
    else {
        if (logger.isWarnEnabled()) {
            logger.warn("Unknown exception type: " + ex.getClass().getName());
        }
        HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, null, headers, status, request);
    }
}
```

So the question is : how to override the exception handler for a specific exception ?
This approach cannot work :

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = { HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.class })
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleConflict(HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException ex, WebRequest request) {
   ...
}
```

Because inside the exception handler class, Spring doesn't let you to define more than a single time a mapping for a specific `Exception` subclass.   So adding this mapping in your custom exception handler is not allowed because Spring already defines a mapping for that exception in the  `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` class.
Concretely, it will prevent the Spring container from starting successfully.
You should get an exception such as :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous @ExceptionHandler method mapped for [class org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException]: {protected org.springframework...
```

To ease client subclasses to override the actual handling/mapping for a specific exception, Spring implemented the logic of each exception caught and handled by itself in a **`protected` method** of the `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` class.
So in your case (overriding the handler of `HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException`), just override `handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported()` that is what you are looking for  :

```
if (ex instanceof HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException) {
    HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED;
    return handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported((HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException) ex, headers, status, request);
}
```

For example in this way :

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported(HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status,
            WebRequest request) {    
        // do your processing
         ...
        // go on (or no) executing the logic defined in the base class 
        return super.handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported(ex, headers, status, request);
    }
}
```

Comment: The overriding approach worked for the method handleHttpMessageNotReadable but not for others from the ResponseEntityExceptionHandler class (example: handleNoHandlerFoundException). Any idea why this could occur?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks davidxxx for this answer and examples. They helped me a lot. thank you!
I did it this way and it worked for me. Here is an example:

```
    @ControllerAdvice
    public class AppExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
        @ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
        public ResponseEntity<?> resourceNotFoundException(final ResourceNotFoundException ex, final WebRequest request) {
            final ErrorDetails errorDetails = new ErrorDetails(new Date(), ex.getMessage(), request.getDescription(false));
            return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDetails, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    @ExceptionHandler(ResourceAlreadyExistsFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> resourceAlreadyExistsFoundException(final ResourceAlreadyExistsFoundException ex, final WebRequest request) {
        final ErrorDetails errorDetails = new ErrorDetails(new Date(), ex.getMessage(), request.getDescription(false));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDetails, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
    ResponseEntity<?> onConstraintValidationException(
            ConstraintViolationException e) {
        List<ErrorDetails> errors = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ConstraintViolation violation : e.getConstraintViolations()) {
            errors.add(
                    new ErrorDetails(new Date(), violation.getPropertyPath().toString(), violation.getMessage()));
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errors, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        ArrayList<ErrorDetails> errors = new ArrayList<>();
        for (FieldError fieldError : ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors()) {
            errors.add(
                    new ErrorDetails(new Date(), fieldError.getField(), fieldError.getDefaultMessage()));
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errors, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> globleExcpetionHandler(final Exception ex, final WebRequest request) {
        final ErrorDetails errorDetails = new ErrorDetails(new Date(), ex.getMessage(), request.getDescription(false));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDetails, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```